# Persistent apache coredumps originating from NewRelic PHP packageEdit

Tags: php, apache, newrelic, ubuntu-22.04, newrelic-platform

I've been having Apache segfaults / core dumps. These stop happening when I disable the NewRelic PHP extension. While this could just be a symptom of a different issue, the same issue (and solution) has worked across multiple servers over the last week or so.

I have tried downgrading the newrelic packages to the previous version, which has not resolved the issue. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Apache 2.4.52.

Has anyone else been experiencing these issues or anything similar?

```
dpkg -l | grep newrelic
ii newrelic-daemon                  10.15.0.4                                   amd64       The New Relic proxy daemon
ii newrelic-php5                    10.15.0.4                                   amd64       The New Relic agent for PHP
ii newrelic-php5-common             10.15.0.4                                   all         Scripts and samples for the New Relic PHP agent
```

Example backtrace:

```
  #0  0x00007fab686dd294 zend_hash_set_bucket_key (libphp8.1.so + 0x2dd294)
  #1  0x00007fab6876530a n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0x36530a)
  #2  0x00007fab686a9dbb zend_do_delayed_early_binding (libphp8.1.so + 0x2a9dbb)
  #3  0x00007fab6936a294 n/a (opcache.so + 0x35294)
  #4  0x00007fab687021ed n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0x3021ed)
  #5  0x00007fab6870f5ec n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0x30f5ec)
  #6  0x00007fab68736c38 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x336c38)
  #7  0x00007fab668b45da nr_zend_call_orig_execute_special (newrelic.so + 0x525da)
  #8  0x00007fab6689429f nr_php_execute_enabled (newrelic.so + 0x3229f)
  #9  0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #10 0x00007fab684fb881 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0xfb881)
  #11 0x00007fab68735053 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x335053)
  #12 0x00007fab668b45da nr_zend_call_orig_execute_special (newrelic.so + 0x525da)
  #13 0x00007fab6689429f nr_php_execute_enabled (newrelic.so + 0x3229f)
  #14 0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #15 0x00007fab684fb5d0 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0xfb5d0)
  #16 0x00007fab68735053 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x335053)
  #17 0x00007fab668b45da nr_zend_call_orig_execute_special (newrelic.so + 0x525da)
  #18 0x00007fab6689429f nr_php_execute_enabled (newrelic.so + 0x3229f)
  #19 0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #20 0x00007fab684fb5d0 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0xfb5d0)
  #21 0x00007fab68735053 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x335053)
  #22 0x00007fab668b45da nr_zend_call_orig_execute_special (newrelic.so + 0x525da)
  #23 0x00007fab6689429f nr_php_execute_enabled (newrelic.so + 0x3229f)
  #24 0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #25 0x00007fab684fb881 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0xfb881)
  #26 0x00007fab68735053 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x335053)
  #27 0x00007fab668b45da nr_zend_call_orig_execute_special (newrelic.so + 0x525da)
  #28 0x00007fab6689429f nr_php_execute_enabled (newrelic.so + 0x3229f)
  #29 0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #30 0x00007fab684fb881 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0xfb881)
  #31 0x00007fab68735053 execute_ex (libphp8.1.so + 0x335053)
  #32 0x00007fab66894597 nr_php_execute_file (newrelic.so + 0x32597)
  #33 0x00007fab66894e7e nr_php_execute (newrelic.so + 0x32e7e)
  #34 0x00007fab6873ee19 zend_execute (libphp8.1.so + 0x33ee19)
  #35 0x00007fab686cf7a0 zend_execute_scripts (libphp8.1.so + 0x2cf7a0)
  #36 0x00007fab6866adea php_execute_script (libphp8.1.so + 0x26adea)
  #37 0x00007fab687b7608 n/a (libphp8.1.so + 0x3b7608)
  #38 0x00005632f1ddcd08 ap_run_handler (apache2 + 0x5bd08)
  #39 0x00005632f1ddebf6 ap_invoke_handler (apache2 + 0x5dbf6)
  #40 0x00005632f1e057e8 ap_process_async_request (apache2 + 0x847e8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack backtrace is not enough to give any definitive answer as to what may be causing the issue. Can you please provide more context?

Furthermore, last resort is to verify you're not running threaded MPM workers setup.